# Unable to Instantiate ViewModel with a Dao argument using ViewModelFactory and "by viewModel()" inside Composables

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I've been trying to instantiate and use a ViewModel inside two Composables, and I've created them a ViewModelFactory, but the project doesn't build for some reason, says Failed to instantiate a ViewModel. I tried to pass LocalContext.current as Application and also tried without passing that, with no success. I want to pass my MainViewModel to both composables and use ViewModelProvider at both of them.

```
    @Composable
fun LoginScreen(navController: NavController){

val viewmodel: MainViewModel = viewModel(LocalContext.current as ComponentActivity)


    @Composable
fun ListingScreen(){

    val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()


    
class MainViewModel(private val dataSource: Dao,
                    application: Application): ViewModel() {

val loginUser: MutableState<User?> = mutableStateOf(null)
private val lastLoginInfo: MutableState<LoginInfo?> = mutableStateOf(null)
lateinit var videoUrlList: List<String>

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        getLastLogin()
    }
    initializeVideoList()
}

private fun initializeVideoList(){
    videoUrlList = listOf<String>("Some links here"

    )
}

fun checkValidity(username: String, password: Int): Boolean{
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val userEntity = dataSource.getUserByLogin(username = username, password = password).collect {
            loginUser.value = it
        }
    }
    return loginUser.value != null
}

fun returnFilename(fileUrl: String): String {
    return fileUrl.substringAfterLast("/")
}

 fun addLogin(loginInfo: LoginInfo= LoginInfo()){
    dataSource.addLogin(loginInfo)
}

private suspend fun getLastLogin(){
    dataSource.getLastLogin().collect {
        lastLoginInfo.value = it
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
private fun checkIfLoginRecent(): Boolean{
    return convert((System.currentTimeMillis()-lastLoginInfo.value!!.loginEndTimeMilli)
        .toDouble(),
        DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        DurationUnit.MINUTES)< 5
}
```

}

```
    class MainViewModelFactory(
    private val dataSource: Dao,
    private val application: Application
): ViewModelProvider.Factory{
    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MainViewModel(dataSource, application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

After edit: Now the project builds but still gives the same error saying it couldn't instantiate viewmodel in composable.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val mainViewModelFactory: MainViewModelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(Database.getInstance(this).Dao, application)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, mainViewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        setContent {
            MyAndroidApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                navController= rememberNavController()
                Navigation(mainViewModel)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example Preview code:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun LoginScreenPreview(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val main: MainActivity = MainActivity()
    val factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            val dao = Database.getInstance(main.applicationContext).Dao

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return MainViewModel( dataSource = dao, main.application) as T
        }
    }
    val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(
        factory =factory)
    TextField(value ="can", onValueChange ={} )
    LoginScreen(navController,  viewmodel = viewModel)
}
```

Comment: `viewModel()` takes a `VieeModelProvider.Factory` as one of its arguments, but you aren't passing an instance of your custom factory to `viewModel()`. How are you expecting that Factory to be used?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you very much for your answer. I changed the code, now i create the viewmodel inside mainactivity and then pass to navigation compose component. Though now it builds, still doesn't work on emulator. For previews, I create an instance of mainactivity() and instantiate factory and all, but it doesn't preview unfortunately. I'd greatly appreciate if you can look at the new code if you manage to find some free time.

Comment: Considering you are not passing `MainViewModelFactory` at all to `viewModel()`, I'm not sure why you expect it to know how to create a `ViewModel` that takes a `Dao`. A simple solution would be to make `ViewModel()` be `AndroidViewModel(app)`, and then get the Dao inside VM constructor `init {` block using the `app` you got via `AndroidViewModel`. Then you can skip passing down the `MainViewModelFactory` because you won't need it. But you can decide which one is better to do.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I did as you say, this way I wouldn't need to pass in the factory,""" (btw I changed the code a bit in the edit, although I incorrectly created mainactivity instance)""", but still can't instantiate view model in preview. Tried these: '
val viewmodel: MainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current!!)[MainViewModel::class.java]
    
val viewmodel2: MainViewModel = viewModel()'